# Why does the state of a Java thread waiting for IO is RUNNABLE?

Tags: java, multithreading

A request to my web application was timed out, I dumped the thread stack with `jstack` and part of the result is :

```
http--2801-4$1476360005" #25 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fa884011000 nid=0x6b67 runnable [0x00007fa87f532000]
     java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    - locked <0x00000000910e2f20> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    - locked <0x00000000910e2e98> (a sun.net.www.http.HttpClient)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1202)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:966)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1316)
    - locked <0x00000000910e2358> (a sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1291)
    - locked <0x00000000910e2358> (a sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection)
    at com.caucho.hessian.client.HessianProxy.sendRequest(HessianProxy.java:298)
    at com.caucho.hessian.client.HessianProxy.invoke(HessianProxy.java:166)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.getSimilarity(Unknown Source)
    at com.coola.component.search.share.SearchClientNew.getSimilarity(SearchClientNew.java:78)
    ...
```

What confuse me is that the state of a thread which is waiting for IO resource should be `BLOCKED` (according to [this post](https://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/multi-threading/java-thread-life-cycle-and-thread-states/)), why it is `RUNNABLE`?

Comment: it is not RUNNING it is RUNNABLE.

Comment: I don't see any "RUNNING" in your thread stack.

Comment: RUNNABLE doesn't means that the thread actually running.

Comment: Sorry, I've update the question